# How do I arrange my multi-lingual REST API?

Tags: rest, spoken-language

I've just began building a multilingual REST API and are unsure on if there's any convention to follow regarding how I should integrate the multilinguality properly.

Below is a list of alternatives I have come up with, not knowing which makes most sense.

**Option 1:**
Language-variable in URI: `http://myapi.com/en/users/john`

**Option 2:**
Returning only error codes for translation client side: 
`GET http://myapi.com/users/john => HTTP 404 {status: false, error_code: "321"}`

**Option 3:**
Returning in all available languages: `GET http://myapi.com/users/john => {status: false, error_en: "User not found", error_sv: "Anvandaren finns inte"}`

Comment: Please describe what 'the multilinguality properly' is in your domain. Can there be different users `john` for different languages?

Comment: No, Data is the same for all languages along with resource names. Only human-readable strings should change

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For [content negotiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_negotiation) as for negotiating the natural language of a representation, HTTP provides the [request header `Accept-Language`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.4):

```
Accept-Language: da, en-gb;q=0.8, en;q=0.7
```

If possible, the server replies to this request with a [response header `Content-Language`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.12):

```
Content-Language: da
```

Only if the resources are *different* resources for *different* languages, the language should be part of the URI. If not, content negotiation should be used.

Comment: In this case, content negotiation would be used to negotiate the language of the human-readable strings in the response only. Non-strings, or strings not intended for people (such as object keys) would not be translated.

Comment: @DonalFellows Yes. From the question I am not sure if this is what is meant by 'a multilingual REST API'. But when in doubt, use the standard :)

Comment: w3c published [an interesting article](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-accept-lang-locales.en) suggesting `Accept-Language` can be a suggestion of language, but that this is not its intended use case, it is rarely changed from the default by users, and is imperfect, especially for locale, and so an alternative method should be offered too.